# Batch file to copy from all user profiles

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I want to generate a batch file that will copy all *.doc and *.xls file types from a user's profile.  I will then set the batch file to run automatically via Scheduled Tasks after-hours when all users are logged out.  Here is what I have:

```
for %%x in (doc xls) do xcopy c:\Users\user1\*.%%x "\\server\i$\User Backups\user1\%computername%\" /c /i /y /s /d
```

This works fine, however, I need to generate a line item in the batch file for each and every user in our organization (user1, user2, etc.) so that I hit all profiles.  When new users are hired, the file needs to be updated with their profile info.  Ideally, I'd like something a bit more automated that is similar to this:

```
for %%x in (doc xls) do xcopy %userprofile%\*.%%x "\\server\i$\User Backups\%username%\%computername%" /c /i /y /s /d
```

The downfall is that by using %userprofile% in place of the 'user1' input, it only runs against the currently logged in user.  Is there another option I could incorporate that wouldn't care about the currently logged in user, and instead just run against all user profiles on a machine?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reg query` to get the list of user profiles from the registry, but you only care about users who have a folder under `C:\Users`, so just loop over those:

```
for /d %%u in (C:\Users\*) do for %%x in (doc xls) do xcopy C:\Users\%%~nu\*.%%x "\\server\i$\User Backups\%%~nu\%computername%\" /c /i /y /s /d
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was able to utilize what you suggested, and consolidate my original script file.  I certainly appreciate your help!

Comment: That's perfect for Win Vista and above, but what about WinXP? How does one loop thru userprofiles then?

Comment: @crosenblum, just replace "C:\Users" with "C:\Documents and Settings" or whatever the localized user profile location is on the machine in question.